# Can SaslAuthenticationException intermittent?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

We had a failure lately caused by Kafka's `SaslAuthenticationException`.
I could see the following in kafka logs:

```
[2024-03-12 04:30:26,424] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=1] Failed authentication with /10.1.119.82 (channelId=10.1.101.72:9092-10.1.119.82:56332-294) (Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism SCRAM-SHA-256) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

This only happened for 1 subscription on 1 worker node and we have several worker nodes running across the docker cluster with tons of subscriptions. We use the same credentials to everything and everywhere else the creds were working fine and we could continue processing as expected.
Anyone ever experienced something similar? I highly doubt the issue is with the set-up as every other topics are working fine and there were 0 changes lately.
Could the `SaslAuthenticationException` be intermittent? Is there any point in re-trying x times?